# How to interpret aiRadioChannel(1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.3.3.1.2.2.1.4) SNMP OID result

Tags: snmp, oid, aruba

I am trying to interpret Aruba AP's radio channels using `aiRadioChannel(1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.3.3.1.2.2.1.4)`, which is not understandable in OID's description

```
    SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.x.x.x.x.0 = INTEGER: 1076
    SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.x.x.x.x.1 = INTEGER: 6
    SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.x.x.x.x.0 = INTEGER: 1140
    SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.x.x.x.x.1 = INTEGER: 11
```

I want to derive channel numbers from this SNMP OID.

Answer (score 0):

From [the MIB reference guide] (https://community.arubanetworks.com/aruba/attachments/aruba/IAP/4680/1/Aruba%20Instant%206.3.1.1-4.0%20MIB%20Reference%20Guide.pdf) (this one is for ArubaOs 6.3.1.1-4.0 but it probably doesn't change that often):

**aiRadioChannel**

- **Syntax** Integer32
- **Max-Access** read-only
- **Status** current
- **Description** Radio channel. The first byte contains primary channel and first two bits of second byte contains indicator for the secondary channel. If first two bits of second byte are 0, it is a 20MHz channel. If first two bits of second byte are 01, the secondary channel is above primary channel, if first two bits of second byte are 10, the secondary channel is below the primary channel.

Does that help you any further?

Comment: description is understandable but we couldn't interpret values as channels